# $\dim (\operatorname{Null}(ST)) \le \dim (\operatorname{Null}(S)) + \dim (\operatorname{Null}(T))$

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't recall the proof of
$$ \dim (\operatorname{Null}(ST)) \le \dim (\operatorname{Null}(S)) + \dim (\operatorname{Null}(T))$$.

Clearly $N(S)$ and $N(ST)$ can't be comparable. And $N(ST) \subseteq Im(T)$ But.. Any hint??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma**: Let $S$ and $T$ be square matrices of size $n$. Then
$$
\text{rank}(ST)\ge \text{rank}(S)+\text{rank}(T)-n.
$$
*Proof*: Denote $U=\text{Im}(T)$ and consider the restriction of $S$ on $U$, that is $S'\colon U\to\mathbb{K}^n$, $S'u=Su$, $\forall u\in U$. Clearly, $\text{Im}(ST)=\text{Im}(S')$ and $\ker(S')=\ker(S)\cap U\subset\ker(S)$. Thus, we have
$$
\text{rank}(ST)=\text{rank}(S')=\underbrace{\text{dim}(U)}_{=\text{rank}(T)}-\text{dim}\ker(S')\ge\text{rank}(T)-\text{dim}\ker(S)=\text{rank}(T)+\text{rank}(S)-n.\ \ \square
$$
By the lemma we have
$$
\text{dim}\ker(ST)\le \text{dim}\ker(S)+\text{dim}\ker(T).
$$
P.S. Generalization for non-square matrices is straightforward.

Comment: In my question if $dim(U)$ $dim(V)$ $dim(W)$  not be same, i.e $S$ and $T$ may not be of same size. Then what will be the conclusion?

Comment: @user152715 Then in the lemma $n$ is the dimension of the "middle" space and the conclusion in terms of kernels is the same. The proof does not use "squareness", just to give a hint and not to take all the happiness of discovery the truth from you :)

Comment: Great... Bingo :D